# Identify and get capitalized words in a string in php

Tags: php

Is there a function or way on how to get the CAPS words on a sentence or string?
Example: `$str = "ABOUT US who we are"`
how am i able to identify and get the capitalized words `"ABOUT US"`and separate it to small letter words `"who we are"`? So that the output would be `$str1 = "ABOUT US"` and `$str2 = "who we are"`... thanks!

Comment: what about `ABOUT us WHO we ARE`?

Comment: that doesn't matter at all. cause all strings to be checked will always have a structure where all CAPS words will be first on the line and small letter words will be next, just like this "CAPS WORDS FIRST small words next"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for it:

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $str, $matches);
```

To match the lowercase words, use this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b([a-z]+)\b/', $str, $matches2);
```

Then you can use functions such as `implode()` to build the strings.

Comment: i'm not super familiar with regex (kinda in learning process) but i think he wants to include spaces and trim (if he want's "ABOUT US" and not "ABOUT" "US" or "ABOUT US ") it shouldn't be too hard to add but as i said i don't wanna risk edit it.

Comment: The string would always have word/s all upper case that will be on the first occurrence and the lower case words will be next to it just like with the example... therefore the string that i will be testing is always something like this "ALL CAPS FIRST all lower case next", so it would be easier to separate the two if only i have the condition on how to do it. of course white spaces before and after each separated strings will be disregarded

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the regular expressions solution, PHP has the neato function [ctype_upper()](https://www.php.net/ctype_upper) which tests whether a string is all uppercase. You can feed the text you're parsing through it one character at a time. If it returns true, add the character to your `$str1`. Once it returns false, add the remainder of the string to `$str2`.

For greater flexibility, you could make $str1 and $str2 elements in an array. Then you can add a new element every time the text you're parsing changes case. For example, the text `"HELLO AND welcome to STACKOVERFLOW bro"` would end up as `["HELLO AND", "welcome to", "STACKOVERFLOW", "bro"]`. Or you could have separate arrays for uppercase and lowercase chunks of the text.