# Split words between UPPER CASE and lower case

Tags: php, regex

If anyone could help me this would be awesome!

I have this:

`TYLLON kevin` -convert-> familyname: `TYLLON`; prename: `kevin`

`VAN AZERTY bert` -convert-> familyname: `VAN AZERTY`; prename: `bert`

`YAHOO BE AWESOME rabbit` -convert-> familyname: `YAHOO BE AWESOME`; prename: `rabbit`

Maybe regex, anyone?

Comment: Show us your attempt and we can show you how to improve it or see where your error is

Comment: I don't have a error, i'm still searching... I suck at regex that's why I ask a question

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht You seem to have misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301415/identify-and-get-capitalized-words-in-a-string-in-php

Comment: @Biffen: Why, i don't ask questions that much?

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht SO is not a service where you ask others to write code for you. It's for asking questions regarding problems you encounter when *you code*.

Comment: @Biffen: Ask a question, is ask a question... if you have a problem and don't know how to solve it... How would you even be possible to write the code?

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Moreover, how do you think most programmers do it? They certainly don't post a question on SO for *every single problem* they encounter. A combination of brains and a good search engine are far more common tools.

Comment: @Biffen Easy dude, I think he got the point. This isn't a "do-it-for-me" service, but a service to help to solve problems with existing code. Since he has no code, I think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe shortest possible answer is by using `preg_split` here using look-arounds:

Use this regex for splitting:

```
/(?<=\p{Lu})\h+(?=\p{Ll})/u
```

Which matches 1 or more horizontal space that is preceded by a uppercase unicode letter and followed by a lowercase unicode letter.

**PS: This solution is unicode compatible.**

**Examples:**

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?<=\p{Lu})\h+(?=\p{Ll})/u', 'YAHOO BE AWESOME rabbit'));
Array
(
    [0] => YAHOO BE AWESOME
    [1] => rabbit
)

print_r(preg_split('/(?<=\p{Lu})\h+(?=\p{Ll})/u', 'VAN AZERTY bert'));
Array
(
    [0] => VAN AZERTY
    [1] => bert
)

print_r(preg_split('/(?<=\p{Lu})\h+(?=\p{Ll})/u', 'TYLLON kevin'));
Array
(
    [0] => TYLLON
    [1] => kevin
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your name strings using the php function [ctype_upper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php):

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are uppercase characters.

You would first have to `explode()` your names and put them in an array. Once you have them in an array you can check for upper case / lower case…

```
<?php
$name_array = array('VAN', 'AZERTY', 'bert');
foreach ($name_array as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_upper($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase is upper case.";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase is lower case / mixed case.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
<?php
   preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $fullname, $upper);
   preg_match_all('/\b([a-z]+)\b/', $fullname, $lower);
   $familyname = implode(' ', $upper[0]);
   $prename = implode(' ', $lower[0]);
   echo $prename.' '.$familyname;
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using string concatenation, use comas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in combination of multiple answers:

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', 'BLA BOEM BABA Kevin', $matches);
```

RESULT: BLA BOEM BABA

```
preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', '', 'VAN MELKEBEKE BLA BOEM BABA Kevin');
```

RESULT: Kevin